# Leakage inductance is function of the air gap

Tags: power-supply, transformer, switch-mode-power-supply

I would like to know why leakage inductance is function of the air gap transformer. How does it influence the leakage flux ? What is the relation between them ?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: It was shown in a paper by Hsu and al. (*Transformer modeling and design for leakage control*) that leakage inductance is not a function of the transformer gap. Increasing the air-gap length decreases the coupling coefficient by decreasing the magnetizing inductance and not by increasing the leakage term: take a 2-winding transformer, measure the leakage with the core across the bobbin, then remove the core and measure the leakage inductance with the bobbin alone, it is almost unchanged.

Comment: I m not able to find your paper on internet ? Can you please tranfer it to me if you know where you can find it. Thank you :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it is no longer in print. It was published in a two-volume book with many papers from Dr. Middlebrook and Dr. Cuk. You can perhaps find them on an auction site. This link contains interesting data http://ridleyengineering.com/hardware/ap310-analyzer/ap300-application/transformer-measurements.html and searching some of the articles published by Dr. Ridley in his design center will also lead you to interesting information on leakage inductance control.

Comment: Thank you I will take a look :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know why leakage inductance is function of the air gap
>   transformer. How does it influence the leakage flux ? What is the
>   relation between them ?

With a transformer core of high effective magnetic permeability, you *could* say that the flux produced by one winding 99.9% couples to the other winding. The closer the coupling is to 100%, the smaller is the leakage flux.

For a core with moderate effective permeability, you might attribute a coupling factor of only 99%. For a core of low effective permeability you might "say" the coupling is around 90%.

Adding a gap to a core of high permeability makes the effective permeability of a transformer smaller and, in turn, the coupling also reduces. A bigger gap reduces the effective permeability even more.

In other words, it isn't the gap itself that creates all the leakage flux but rather the drop in overall permeability making the core "less attractive" of a "path" for magnetic fields to flow along.

An effective relative permeability of 10 is only 10 times that of air and, although most flux would flow through that core, a decent proportion (say 10%) will short cut the core and return back through the air. Whether you use a high permeability core with a gap to bring it down from 1000 to 10 or, you use an un-gapped core of low permeability (10), the effect is the same.

Comment: Thank you Andy again ! What you mean is that when I used a transformer with a low permeability, the flux will be less concentrated around the core and so there is some flux which will not be linked to the other coil ? which leads to leakage inductance ?

Comment: @Jess yes, correct. Air becomes a more tenable path for magnetism to flow down. We can think of the core as being in parallel with the air and, the core has low "resistance" to the flow of magnetism hence it "conducts" the most flux just like two resistors in parallel where the lowest value resistor takes most of the current. It's called "reluctance" in magnetic terms i.e. a high perm core has low reluctance to flux and therefore flux wants to flow that path.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean.  The path with the highest reluctance goes back to the same coil where as the path with the lowest reluctance goes to the other coil. The path with the lowest reluctance is common to the both coils whereas there are two path with the two different highest reluctances which are relative to each coil.

Comment: Think of it like resistors in parallel; the lowest resistance (reluctance) takes most of the current (flux).

Comment: I agree with you ! But it can't be parallel resistance as the leakage flux should not be linked to the secondary coil ?

Comment: Parallel resistors where one resistor does not “couple” to the other coil.

Comment: You re right :)

Comment: According to @Verbal Kint what I said is actually wrong ... The leakage flux is always the same, nevertheless as the permeability decrease with the length of the air gap, the magnetizing inductance decrease... And so the coupling factor is lower as the leakage inductance remains constant.

Comment: With a lower permeability core the magnetization inductance is lowered proportionately. And with a core of air the mag inductance is at its minimum. That is true. However, I would say (with no evidence to back up what I’m saying) that, with a core of high permeability, the majority of the field is inclined to follow the core in directions and distances that wouldn’t otherwise have been possible with no core AND, in my opinion, could give opportunity for leakage to occur not close to the coil but at those greater distances. We’re into physics (not EE) so, if more could be found, I’m interested.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) It makes sense to me !

Answer (score 1):

the electrical representation of leakage flux is leakage inductance. 
Leakage flux : It is that flux which is doesn't link primary and secondary.
Useful flux is that which links primary and secondary.